# Hawkular server setup using maven give me error during build

Tags: maven

Hawkular server setup using maven give me error during build. I am getting below error after run below command :

```
mvn clean install -Pdev -DskipTests -e
```

I am using git hub souce code to build this using link : https://github.com/hawkular/hawkular-apm/tree/master

```
[WARNING] npm WARN deprecated babel@6.5.2: Babel's CLI commands have been moved from the babel package to the babel-cli package
[WARNING] npm WARN deprecated vinyl-map@1.0.1: Missing dependencies resolved in v1.0.2 (Run 'npm update --save vinyl-map' to update package.json)
[WARNING] npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
[WARNING] npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
[WARNING] npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
[WARNING] npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
[WARNING] npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.7: use uuid module instead
[WARNING] npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@2.0.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Hawkular APM ....................................... SUCCESS [ 11.622 s]
[INFO] Hawkular APM::Client::Instrumentation JVM .......... SUCCESS [  2.024 s]
[INFO] Hawkular APM::API .................................. SUCCESS [ 12.477 s]
[INFO] Hawkular APM::Client::API .......................... SUCCESS [  1.301 s]
[INFO] Hawkular APM::Server::API .......................... SUCCESS [  4.397 s]
[INFO] Hawkular APM::Tests::Parent ........................ SUCCESS [  0.743 s]
[INFO] Hawkular APM::Tests::Common ........................ SUCCESS [  0.942 s]
[INFO] Hawkular APM::Client::Collector .................... SUCCESS [  1.769 s]
[INFO] Hawkular APM::Client::Trace Publisher REST Client .. SUCCESS [  0.600 s]
[INFO] Hawkular APM::Client::Instrumenter ................. SUCCESS [  3.242 s]
[INFO] Hawkular APM::Client::Config Service REST Client ... SUCCESS [  0.672 s]
[INFO] Hawkular APM::Client::Agent ........................ SUCCESS [ 11.770 s]
[INFO] Hawkular APM::Client::OpenTracing .................. SUCCESS [  2.608 s]
[INFO] Hawkular APM::Client::OpenTracing Agent ............ SUCCESS [  2.005 s]
[INFO] Hawkular APM::Client::Analytics Service REST Client  SUCCESS [  0.599 s]
[INFO] Hawkular APM::Client::Kafka ........................ SUCCESS [  0.877 s]
[INFO] Hawkular APM::Client::Trace Service REST Client .... SUCCESS [  0.556 s]
[INFO] Hawkular APM::Examples::Vertx Opentracing .......... SUCCESS [  0.550 s]
[INFO] Hawkular APM::Examples::Vertx Opentracing::Common .. SUCCESS [  1.142 s]
[INFO] Hawkular APM::Examples::Vertx Opentracing::Account Manager SUCCESS [  3.121 s]
[INFO] Hawkular APM::Examples::Vertx Opentracing::Inventory Manager SUCCESS [  2.613 s]
[INFO] Hawkular APM::Examples::Vertx Opentracing::Order Log SUCCESS [  2.547 s]
[INFO] Hawkular APM::Examples::Vertx Opentracing::Order Manager SUCCESS [  2.939 s]
[INFO] Hawkular APM::Server::Elasticsearch ................ SUCCESS [  4.698 s]
[INFO] Hawkular APM::Server::Infinispan ................... SUCCESS [  1.564 s]
[INFO] Hawkular APM::Server::Processors ................... SUCCESS [  1.926 s]
[INFO] Hawkular APM::Server::Processors::Zipkin ........... SUCCESS [  1.488 s]
[INFO] Hawkular APM::Server::JMS .......................... SUCCESS [  2.246 s]
[INFO] Hawkular APM::Server::Kafka ........................ SUCCESS [  1.072 s]
[INFO] Hawkular APM::Server::Processors::Alerts Publisher . SUCCESS [  1.325 s]
[INFO] Hawkular APM::Server::REST ......................... SUCCESS [  2.697 s]
[INFO] Hawkular APM::Server::Security Provider::JAAS ...... SUCCESS [  0.566 s]
[INFO] Hawkular APM::Server::Zipkin REST .................. SUCCESS [  0.690 s]
[INFO] Hawkular APM::Server::Zipkin WAR ................... SUCCESS [  2.372 s]
[INFO] Hawkular APM::Server::WAR .......................... SUCCESS [  2.235 s]
[INFO] Hawkular APM::UI::Console .......................... FAILURE [ 28.713 s]
[INFO] Hawkular APM::Distribution ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Hawkular APM::Tests::App::Swarm polyglot OpenTracing SKIPPED
[INFO] Hawkular APM::Tests::OpenTracing Agent ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Hawkular APM::Tests::Containers::Jetty ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Hawkular APM::Tests::Containers::Standalone ........ SKIPPED
[INFO] Hawkular APM::Tests::Containers::Wildfly ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] Hawkular APM::Tests::Instrumentation ............... SKIPPED
[INFO] Hawkular APM::Tests::Instrumentation Test Framework  SKIPPED
[INFO] Hawkular APM::Tests::Distribution .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 02:05 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-01-18T03:45:12-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 127M/239M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.0:npm (npm install) on project hawkular-apm-ui: Failed to run task: 'npm install' failed. (error code 137) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.0:npm (npm install) on project hawkular-apm-ui: Failed to run task
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Failed to run task
        at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.mojo.AbstractFrontendMojo.execute(AbstractFrontendMojo.java:95)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.TaskRunnerException: 'npm install' failed. (error code 137)
        at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.NodeTaskExecutor.execute(NodeTaskExecutor.java:60)
        at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.mojo.NpmMojo.execute(NpmMojo.java:62)
        at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.mojo.AbstractFrontendMojo.execute(AbstractFrontendMojo.java:89)
        ... 22 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :hawkular-apm-ui
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks!!

I was fixed this issue at my end. I update ui pom.xml file for npm and bower install with install --allow-root. :)